# How to display NiFi login without kerberos or LDAP

Tags: ldap, apache-nifi, kerberos, cloudera

everyone,

I'm trying to set up user authentication by username/password in Apache NiFi, but without using Kerberos or LDAP.

her used nifi toolkit to generate ssl certificates, i have started nifi by https. but i want you to ask me to log in as minimally as possible without installing extras.
is this possible? or is it required to have an external user management system?

- I am using Ubuntu localhost, one node in my laptop

for instance

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The login page is displayed when you have configured NiFi with an identity provider. The two provided identity providers are LDAP and Kerberos, but you can also implement your own as it is an extension point. Other ways to authenticate to NiFi are client certificate, SPNEGO, OIDC, and Knox.

Comment: Hi Bryan, for the option (NiFi are client certificate) I used nifi-toolkit to generate the ssl certificate, with that I already have Nifi over https 
but I don't get the login prompt

Comment: NiFi running over https is not a client certificate, that is a server certificate... a client certificate means you imported a p12 into your browser for the end user, there will be no login prompt because your browser will submit the cert and nifi will check it

Comment: thank you very much, yes I can emit the p12, but I was not clear that this option is a kind of customer authentication method. anyway I am interested in the login option. thank you very much